# Z index dropdown menu

Tags: css, indexing

I'm having problems with where to place the right z-index css code.

My dropdown menu is not on top of all the content as you can see here: http://bit.ly/18j63r4

I've tried to add the z-index code everywhere but it just doesn't seem to work for me.

Hope you can help me out!

(I can't access all the css code as I'm using a ecommerce standard platform. The z index code needs to be placed somewhere in the .dropdown or .kolommen css code.
Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

<del>You've got `z-index:999` on your **`<div class="nav">`** inside `<div class="product" id="filterContainer">`. Simply remove it and drop down menu will be shown on top of it.</del>

**Edit:**

Since you can't access all of the code (maybe you can override it in you css ?) it is hard to help you. If you can, set `z-index:1000` to `#header-modules .h-left {
z-index: 1000;
}`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry, forgot to mention that I cannot acces all the code as I'm using a ecommerce platform. So removing the zindex inside the div class product is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the existing z-index from

```
#filterContainer .nav {
}
```

Makes it work...

It's also worth nothing that z-index will only work on positioned elements

Answer (score 0):

'#header_2_inner' for this element add property

```
{position: relative;
z-index: 9999;}
```

it will  help you

or for

```
#filterContainer .nav {
   font-size: 11px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

add z-index:2

```
#filterContainer .nav {
font-size: 11px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2; 
}
```